# AccessExclusive lock origin

Tags: postgresql

I am running the following query in first transaction:

```
BEGIN ISOLATION LEVEL repeatable read;
SELECT balance from "Users" WHERE id = 1 FOR UPDATE;
UPDATE "Users" SET "balance"="balance"+1 WHERE id = 1;
```

Then the second, from different connection which is exactly same. On `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE` it's waiting.

Then I run the following to see the locks

```
select t.relname,l.locktype,l.tuple,page,virtualtransaction,pid,mode,granted from pg_locks l, pg_stat_all_tables t where l.relation=t.relid order by relation asc;
```

It shows row locks (ROW SHARE, ROW EXCLUSIVE), which is fine. But I also see

```
Users   tuple   9   0   11/17085    199957  AccessExclusiveLock TRUE
```

According to documentation `AccessExclusiveLock` comes from:

> Acquired by the ALTER TABLE, DROP TABLE, TRUNCATE, REINDEX, CLUSTER,
> and VACUUM FULL commands. This is also the default lock mode for LOCK
> TABLE statements that do not specify a mode explicitly.

I am not explicitly doing any of them and I can't find in docs how implicitly this lock is acquired. Moreover, what means tuple lock type and 9?

update #1:

I used the following query to get more info:

```
SELECT a.datname,
         l.relation::regclass,
         l.transactionid,
         l.mode,
         l.GRANTED,
         a.usename,
         a.query,
         a.query_start,
         age(now(), a.query_start) AS "age",
         a.pid
FROM pg_stat_activity a
JOIN pg_locks l ON l.pid = a.pid
ORDER BY a.query_start;
```

So indeed database is same, query is the one that is blocked.

```
mydb    "Users"     AccessExclusiveLock TRUE    appuserdev  SELECT balance from "Users" WHERE id = 1 for update;    2021-08-30 08:06:38.864007+00   00:08:06.978082 205464
```

Comment: You are right, these queries won't take an `ACCESS EXCLUSIVE` lock on the table. That must be something else, perhaps on a different database.

Comment: Well, my both transactions are started for the same database. How can I see the query that caused `AccessExclusiveLock` ?

Comment: You'd have to log all queries to be sure. Add the database to the query and see if it is the same. If yes, it must be a different statement in your own transaction.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe: I've updated my post. DB is same.

Comment: I'd say that is impossible...

Comment: Do you know what lock type of `tuple` in this particular lock may imply?

Comment: Row locks are stored on the row itself, they are not maintained in the lock table. So you don't see them in `pg_locks`. What you see are table locks.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe That is only true when the row lock is not being waited on.  When being waited on, an entry for it in the lock table is created.  Otherwise, there would be no way to detect deadlocks on rows.

Comment: @jjanes That's what I wanted to say when I said "maintained". I meant "kept". Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: But now thinking about it, I don't think it would be necessary to do that for detecting deadlocks.  Maybe that is just for "discoverability" purposes?

Answer (score 0):

The docs you are reading apply to `AccessExclusiveLock` on *tables*.  But what you are seeing is not a table lock.  I don't think the lock modes for non-tables are explicitly documented anywhere, but you can generally figure it out through analogy.

On the other hand, I also don't see what you see.  I see an ExclusiveLock, not an AccessExclusiveLock, being held on the tuple.

Comment: Could it be related to having cluster?